# USB joystick with Linux only works when I disconnected and reconnected its

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, debian

HI!

I have a problem that it can easy, but I didn't find a solution yet.

When I turn on my computer using a Debian or Ubuntu and tried to use the joystick the commands of joystick doesn't pass to SO. Once I disconnect and reconnect the joystick on USB port it pass to work.

Environment:

SO: Debian 5.0 and Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

lsusb - executed this command before disconnect and reconnected the joystick result is equal:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
**Bus 007 Device 004: ID 068e:00af CH Products, Inc.** 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 04d9:1400 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

dmesg - relevants part only:

```
...
[    6.213666] usb 7-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    6.264813] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=068e, idProduct=00af
[    6.264816] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    6.264818] usb 7-2: Product: Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick
[    6.264819] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: CH PRODUCTS
[    6.269849] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
[    6.286942] input: HID 04d9:1400 as /class/input/input0
[    6.286942] input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 04d9:1400] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
[    6.315247] input: HID 04d9:1400 as /class/input/input1
[    6.315247] input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [HID 04d9:1400] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
[    6.357061] input: CH PRODUCTS Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick as /class/input/input2
[    6.357061] input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [CH PRODUCTS Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2
[    6.357061] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    6.357061] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver

...

[ 6377.097243] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, address 3
[ 6379.225161] usb 7-2: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
[ 6379.408990] usb 7-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 6379.615388] input: CH PRODUCTS Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick as /class/input/input6
[ 6379.694649] input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [CH PRODUCTS Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2
[ 6379.700445] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=068e, idProduct=00af
[ 6379.700445] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6379.700445] usb 7-2: Product: Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick
[ 6379.700445] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: CH PRODUCTS**
```

/proc/bus/usb/devices:

```
T:  Bus=07 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=068e ProdID=00af Rev= 0.00
S:  Manufacturer=CH PRODUCTS
S:  Product=Megatron OEM 2 Axis 1 Button Joystick
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr= 32mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   5 Ivl=10ms
```

Device:
    /dev/input/js0

I used to test cat /dev/input/js0 and my application.

I tried to access remotely with ssh, because my keyboard use USB port too, and executed the commands down:

```
# modprobe -r joydev
# modprobe -r usbhid
# modprobe usbhid
# modprobe joydev
```

The joystick doesn't work after I execute commands above.

What is happening?

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem.

I tried a lot and one coworker spoke that I should reload the modules. I tried some combination and this combination work:

```
rmmod joydev
rmmod uhci_hcd
modprobe uhci_hcd
modprobe joydev
```

I input this lines in my /etc/rc.local and joystick work very well.

I need to understand better how it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tested a few hours and there a three solutions.
The easiest:
simply type

> # lsusb -v -d 068e:00af

in the terminal

the cleanest:
load the usbhid module with quirk parameter:

```
# rmmod usbhid && modprobe usbhid quirk=0x068e:0x00af:0x8
```

or for persistent solution better

> # echo "options usbhid quirks=0x068e:0x00af:0x8" > /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid

the "hard" way:

patch the /usr/src/linux/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c (can look different in other kernel versions):

> --- /usr/src/linux-2.6.27.45-0.1_old/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c  2010-02-23
>   12:21:38.000000000 +0100
>   +++ /usr/src/linux-2.6.27.45-0.1_new/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c  2010-11-22
>   17:59:05.000000000 +0100 @@ -102,6
>   +102,9 @@  #define USB_VENDOR_ID_BERKSHIRE        0x0c98
>
> #define USB_DEVICE_ID_BERKSHIRE_PCWD 0x1140
>   +#define USB_VENDOR_ID_CH     0x068e
>   +#define USB_DEVICE_ID_CH_2AXIS_1BUTTON   0x00af
>   +  #define USB_VENDOR_ID_CHERRY       0x046a  #define
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_CHERRY_CYMOTION 0x0023
>   @@ -624,6 +627,7 @@ static const
>   struct hid_blacklist {    {
>   USB_VENDOR_ID_ATEN,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_ATEN_2PORTKVM,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET },    {
>   USB_VENDOR_ID_ATEN,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_ATEN_4PORTKVM,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET },    {
>   USB_VENDOR_ID_ATEN,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_ATEN_4PORTKVMC,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET },
>   + { USB_VENDOR_ID_CH, USB_DEVICE_ID_CH_2AXIS_1BUTTON,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET},     {
>   USB_VENDOR_ID_DMI,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_DMI_ENC, HID_QUIRK_NOGET
>   },    { USB_VENDOR_ID_ELO,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_ELO_TS2700,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET },    {
>   USB_VENDOR_ID_LOGITECH,
>   USB_DEVICE_ID_LOGITECH_EXTREME_3D,
>   HID_QUIRK_NOGET },